# ¿Cómo enviar un parámetro a un procedimiento almacenado en XtraReports?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Buen día.

Tengo un informe diseñado en XtraReports de Devexpress para Windows Forms de Visual Studio 2015 y éste está enlazado a un DataSet, y el DataSet tiene un enlace (en tiempo de diseño) a un procedimiento almacenado (SQL Server) el cual tiene un sólo parámetro.

Para ver el **informe** uso este código *(que funciona de maravilla sin enviar ningún parámetro al procedimiento almacenado)*.

```
//El form 'frmVistaPreviaInformes' contiene un visor de informes propio de Devexpress
Informes.frmVistaPreviaInformes inf = new Informes.frmVistaPreviaInformes();
 
documentViewer1.DocumentSource = xtraReportRecibo;
xtraReportRecibo.CreateDocument();
```

Pero al añadir un parámetro en el procedimiento, sucede esto:
[image: Error de llenado]

**Como enviar un valor de parámetro desde código a un procedimiento almacenado en XtraReports?**
Ayuda..., gracias por su respuesta.

Comment: Falta información a tu pregunta, puedes añadir el código de como añades el parámetro y el procedimiento sql que tienes enlazado?

Comment: `creatre procedure pa_temrecibopago
@idc int
begin
select total, nombrecliente, fecha, descripcion from venta where idcliente0@idc
end`